# Read more content not displayed loops back to blog page

Tags: read-more

When I post a blog it automatically splits with read more. I want to know how to show the rest of the content. I am using nexus template .

Comment: Please add a link to the theme’s source code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` or `front-page.php` (if any):

#### Find

```
the_excerpt()
```

#### Replace with

```
the_content()
```

I din't check the Nexus theme. If you are unable to find `the_excerpt()`, then try locating any custom function within the loop:

> `while ( have_posts() : the_post() )` and `endwhile`.